# Transversality condition for infinite time horizon; Pontryagin Maximum principle

Tags: control-theory, transversality

I want to solve a optimal control problem with the Pontryagin-Maximum-Principle, given following differential equation:

$\dot x(t)=(a+b-c(t))x-c(t)\\
x(0)=x_0$

Regarding to the conditions:
$x\geq0$
maximizing $U_{Ges}=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-rt} U(c(t))dt$

How can i derive the following transversality conditions? 
$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}{e^{-rt}p(t)}\geq 0 \\
\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}{e^{-rt}p(t)x(t)}=0$

I set up all necessary condition for finding an optimal control c(t) but cannot find any derivation of the transversality conditions for infinite time horizons like that.

Comment: Transversality conditions at infinity are subtle, for your type of functional see [Aseev-Kryazhimskii The Pontryagin Maximum Principle for Infinite-Horizon Optimal Controls](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.8359&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Corollaries 5.2-5.3. They also give some counterexamples in Section 2.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you very much. For my type of functional its pretty good. I wonder if i can add the variable $t$ on the righthandside of the state equation like $\dot x=f(x(t),u(t),t)$. Does the proof change or does it stay the same?

Comment: I did not really delve into the proof, so can't help you there, I am afraid.